# open folder of file opened in Preview on a mac

Tags: mac, finder, preview.app

I am previewing a file in Preview (some application opened the file for me).

Now I think it's interesting and want to put it aside, from the finder application, as I want to drag it into google drive or some cloud.

Can I do that in some way, pop up a finder with the file selected ?
I can't find anything in the menu but that would seem useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use File menu > Move to… & put it on the desktop etc

Comment: yeah but I'd like to put it on google drive, I'd like to jump to the directory where it's contained in the finder, to drag ad drop it to my drive.

Comment: Move to… will move to anywhere you like, inc Google Drive, as fast as dragging it.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution:

1. Automator script for a new service:
   [image]
2. Applescript code:

```bsh
tell application "System Events"
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    if "TextEdit" is in activeApp then
        tell application "TextEdit"
            tell front document
                set apath to (its path) as text
                tell application "Finder" to open item (apath as POSIX file)'s container's container window
            end tell
        end tell
    else if "Preview" is in activeApp then
        tell application "Preview"
            tell front document
                set apath to (its path) as text
                tell application "Finder" to open item (apath as POSIX file)'s container's container window
            end tell
        end tell
    else
        display dialog ("This Automator works only from TextEdit/Preview app!")
    end if
end tell


tell application "Finder"
    activate
end tell


return
```

3. I saved the service as "Open Folder from TextEdit or Preview". The service file should be located here: `/Users/<username>/Library/Services`
4. System settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts => Services (from the left panel) => General section => Open Folder from TextEdit or Preview CTRL+ALT+CMD+F

This trick is very very useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

3 options:

- right click and "move to"
- hold "option" and drag a copy of it
  to your desktop or another folder/location.  this creates a duplicate
  of it as you drag it.
- click and copy (command+c) then click elsewhere and paste (command+v).. also creates a copy of it...

Comment: I am in preview and some application opened the file for me. I don't know where it is beside clicking on the file name looking at the location then navigating manually to it..